Client Certificate Authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API is not working in IIS
i made certificate authentication in .Net core (api core) using client certificate .pfx file and this works well locally but doesn't work after publish the code and the .pfx file on iis.
I am sending all the steps which I already did.

Install the Client Certificate on IIS
Ensure that the client certificate (.pfx file) is properly installed on the server where IIS is running. Here are the steps to install the certificate:

Open the Certificates MMC:
Run mmc.exe.
Go to File -> Add/Remove Snap-in....
Select Certificates and click Add.
Choose Computer account, then Next, and then Local computer.
Click Finish and OK.
Import the .pfx File:
In the Certificates MMC, expand Personal -> Certificates.
Right-click on Certificates, choose All Tasks -> Import....
Follow the wizard to import the .pfx file. Make sure to select the option to allow the private key to be exported if needed.
2. Configure IIS to Require Client Certificates
Ensure that IIS is configured to require client certificates for your application. Here’s how to do it:
Open IIS Manager:
Run inetmgr to open IIS Manager.
Select Your Site:
In the left-hand Connections pane, select your site.
Open SSL Settings:
Double-click on SSL Settings in the middle pane.
Configure SSL Settings:
Ensure that Require SSL is checked.
Set the Client Certificates to Require or Accept depending on your requirement.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCertificate(options =>
        {
            options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
            options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                {
                    // Custom validation logic here
                    context.Success();
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.Fail("Invalid certificate");
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });

    services.AddAuthorization();
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}


This process is woring in my local when I run the APIs local and apply through postman but after publishing to IIS this is not working.
I wanted to know where is the gap.

without a CA trusted cert the users would have to install that cert and trust it. (which is a little dangerous if your cert is ever stolen)  Are they being prompted?  If you receive an error you should include that in your post. You may want to purchase a cert for your domain.  (there are free options if this is not a business... i.e. letsencrypt)
